# dyld: Library not loaded, even though path is specified in Makefile

Tags: macos, command-line, dynamic-library

I have a Fortran program which I run on my macOS 10.12.6. The code is compiled using a Makefile, in which all the libraries included have their path included as well. For one of the libraries (and only one) my executable can't seem to be able to find it. My code compiles correctly but I get this runtime error at the beginning of the program:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libslatec.so
  Referenced from: path_to_PWD/exe/executable
  Reason: image not found
```

Here's how I am adding my library:

```
LIB_SLATEC = -L$(HOME)/usr/lib/slatec/lib -lslatec
```

If I do `ls $HOME/usr/lib/slatec/lib` I get: `libslatec.so`.

Running `otool -L path_to_exe | grep slatec` I get: `libslatec.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)`. I see that there is no path specified there. If I copy the library into my `$PWD` the code runs as expected. I have also tried adding the library path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but that did not change anything.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: can you check the permissions on the library and each directory in the path to the library? otherwise `*.so` are kinda rare, and are usually instead `*.dylib` on macOS...

Comment: @thrig I installed all the libraries, including this one, in my $HOME/usr/lib so I have all the permissions needed.

Comment: How was the.so file created?

Comment: @Mark I downloaded the source files from here: http://www.netlib.org/slatec/ and compiled them following this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200711/is-it-possible-to-compile-the-slatec-library-on-mac-os-x

Comment: That works if you install in /usr/local/lib as you are in a differewnt directory that is not in the standard load path you need to read https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/UsingDynamicLibraries.html or use static libraries - which might mean deleteing the .so and leaving the .a files

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the input/link. I know putting in /usr/local/lib works but I don't understand why it fails when I add the path to: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: When do you add the path - when building or running - running I thi9nk is where that is needed

Comment: Because opf these things I use macports to install binaries see https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=slatec also note macports can be installed in your home directory if you do not have admin rights